# Using Firefox website information in C++ program

Tags: c++, html, firefox, plugins

I am trying to extract information from "about:plugins" website when you use Firefox web browser. I want to be able to use the contents of the website in my C++ program. Only way I know how to use content from another location is reading from a file.

What I am trying to do is read the file name and file path for each plugin from about:plugin'

Not sure if I could send this information to a file and then read it from there, but that seems like double work since if it output to file, I could just read it from there.

Needed to know how to extract information from the Firefox website in order to be used in a C++ program.

Comment: Nice story. What's your question?

Comment: how to extract information from firefox website in order to be used in a C++ program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse the pluginreg.dat file, you can find it in:

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxx.default

To obtain the AppData

```
char cAppData[MAX_PATH];
if(SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL, cAppData, CSIDL_APPDATA, false))               
{
 // To obtain the profile name, parse the profiles.ini file in the folder
 // ...AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox

 // ...

}
```

Comment: Will this file be in a different location for every user? How would I find it for a different user? How could I find the path file from C++? I could not use my own absolute filepath if someone else used my program.

Comment: @user3403720 Why would you accept an answer if you don't actually know it solves your problem?